# Custom BlackBerry application uploader

Tags: java, blackberry, smartphone

I am looking for a place to start to design a Java application that could load a compiled (and perhaps signed or perhaps not) blackberry app onto a device. This means device enumeration + a means of installing / uploading the app onto the device. I know blackberry provides some programs to do with with their JDK but I want to design my own.

Anyone done / attempted this before?

Thanks

Comment: This already exists: javaloader. Is a portable exe file that is included with JDE. Installs and uninstalls both signed and unsigned cods.

Comment: I know blackberry provides some programs -> I use javaloader now but I would like to build my own tool :)

Comment: Well, you could make a GUI to javaloader to make it more user friendly. Otherwise, I don't know where are you going to find the technical documentation describing how to access BB devices the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlackBerry OS includes some classes for installing byte arrays as code modules. Look at [net.rim.device.api.system.CodeModuleManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/CodeModuleManager.html). You'll have to define your own transport (TCP/IP? Bluetooth? USB?) to get the bytes from the BlackBerry COD into your application.